# How to output CSS files to single directory from several input directories?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Is there a configuration option that will enable me to output scss files located in several directories? I.E.:

```
foo / foo.scss
bar / bar.scss
baz / baz.scss
```

into a single output directory

```
css / foo.css
      bar.css
      baz.css
```

Comment: Have you tried `add_import_path` in your config.rb?  http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/

Comment: I think that just adds to the list of available import locations - what I'm looking for is to control the output directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating a `sass` directory with dummy files for each of your components:

```
project/
  css/
    foo.css
    bar.css
    baz.css
  modules/
    foo/
      foo.scss
    bar/
      bar.scss
    baz/
      baz.scss
  sass/
    foo.scss
    bar.scss
    baz.scss
```

Each dummy file should import the corresponding component.

sass/foo.scss:

```
@import "../modules/foo/foo.scss";
```

When you have all dummy files set up, run `sass --update sass:css` from the root of your project.